# BlobServiceClient takes forever to read files from Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the following code that retrieves json files from Blob storage. It takes about 2-3 seconds to return 15000 file names.

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient blobContainer = blobServiceClient .GetBlobContainerClient("ContainerName");
var foundItems = blobServiceClient.FindBlobsByTags("Client = 'AAA' ").ToList();

foreach (var blob in foundItems)
  {
    myList.Add(blob.BlobName);
  }
```

Now I want to read the content from each file. Files are pretty small( about 500B for each json file), but it takes forever and I have to cancel the request.

```
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("ContainerName");
            var foundItems = blobServiceClient.FindBlobsByTags("Client = 'AAA'").ToList();
            foreach (var blob in foundItems)
            {

                var blobClient2 = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobClient(blob.BlobName);
                BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient2.DownloadAsync();
                var content = download.Content;
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(content))
                {
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                        myList.Add(line);
                    }
     
                }
            }
```

From my debugging, the following line takes forever. Is this proper way to read files from blob storage?

```
BlobDownloadInfo download = await blobClient2.DownloadAsync();
```

**More testings:**

If I limit the `foreach` loop to 200 items, it takes about 10 seconds and 90 seconds for 500 items

```
if (++count == 200) break;
```

Are there any other ways to read the content from the files?

Comment: just curious...what happened to `And LastModifiedDate > {date}` in the blob filter in your second example? It will pull ALL files. Right? Maybe not, but that could be the slow down.

Comment: @SimonWilson I was editing code and forgot to update both. The returned results(file names) are the same. Although smaller result does process quicker. Let's say if the return result only contains 50 file names, It takes like 3-4 seconds, but it has over 10000, I waited 20+ mins and had to cancel the request.

Comment: Look into parallel task 'execution' using `Task.WhenAll` for example and see if that helps.